# Logstash conditionnal in message

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm using ELK docker stack to aggregate and analyze logs from differents sources but I've got a problem with my logstash configuration.

Filebeat redirects the flow into logstash and I've nothing on Elasticsearch so I think there is a problem in logstash configuration.

I have two differents kinds of logs from my docker logs :

1. HTTP request logs

   2019-01-29T18:35:15.423Z HTTP INFO "POST /myroute/?param1=test" 201 41 - 44.014 ms
2. APP logs

   2019-01-29T18:48:19.657Z APP ERROR : {"code":201,"message":"ok"}

I would like to check the log and mutate it when I detect if it's "APP" or "HTTP". So, here, my logstash configuration

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
    if "HTTP" in [message] {
      grok {
          mapping => { "message" => %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:type} %{LOGLEVEL:level} "%{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:url}" %{INT:code} %{INT:bytes} - %{GREEDYDATA:response_time}
      }
    }
    else if "APP" in [message] {
      grok {
          mapping => { "message" => %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:type} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:jsonstring}  }
      }
      json {
            source => "jsonstring"
            target => "doc"
      }
      mutate {
        add_field => {
          "code" => "%{[doc][code]}"
          "message" => "%{[doc][message]}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost"] 
    } 
}
```

I think there is a problem when I try to check the content of the message but I don't know how to resolve it. Any idea ?

Thank you very much !

EDIT :

I fix some problem in my configuration but it still doesn't work

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
    if [message] =~ /HTTP/  {
      grok {
          mapping => { "message" => %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:type} %{LOGLEVEL:level} "%{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:url}" %{INT:code} %{INT:bytes} - %{GREEDYDATA:response_time}
      }
    }
    else if [message] =~ /APP/ {
      grok {
          mapping => { "message" => %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:type} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:jsonstring}  }
      }
      json {
            source => "jsonstring"
            target => "doc"
      }
      mutate {
        add_field => {
          "code" => "%{[doc][code]}"
          "message" => "%{[doc][message]}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost"] 
    } 
}
```

EDIT 2 :

logstash.stdout logs

```
 Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, \", ', -, [, { at line 10, column 37 (byte 149) after filter {\n    if \"HTTP\" in [message] {\n      grok {\n          mapping => { \"message\" => ", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:41:in `compile_imperative'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:49:in `compile_graph'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in `map'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:10:in `compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:149:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:22:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:90:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:42:in `block in execute'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:92:in `block in exclusive'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:148:in `synchronize'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:92:in `exclusive'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:38:in `execute'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:317:in `block in converge_state'"
```

Nobody ? :(

Comment: Do you have any kind of output/logs when you are running logstash? Also when troubleshooting an issue, it can be useful to have a file/stdout output to see what's logstash is processing.

Comment: Yes I updated my first post with logs

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration was syntactically wrong, as shown by the message `Expected one of`. First you were missing a `}`, then the grok pattern had to declared as a String, between `"`, with the `"` in the String escaped (as `\"`) and in the grok filter, the option is match, not mapping.

So correcting all that, starting for the first conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
    if "HTTP" in [message] {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:type} %{LOGLEVEL:level} \"%{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:url}\" %{INT:code} %{INT:bytes} - %{GREEDYDATA:response_time}" }
        }
    } else if "APP" in [message] {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:type} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:jsonstring}"  }
        }
        json {
            source => "jsonstring"
            target => "doc"
        }
        mutate {
            add_field => {
                "code" => "%{[doc][code]}"
                "message" => "%{[doc][message]}"
            }
        }
    }
}

output { 
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost"] 
    } 
}
```